# Python Simulation: Total Website Traffic Qty Estimation using Personas Segments

Tags: python, simulation, traffic

I need to estimate future website traffic & conversion volume based on:

1)  Baseline historical averages for 6 differing types of traffic segments

2)  How each of those distinct visitor segments interacts with 5 unique content groups

After searching the internet I've concluded modules exist that can easily be
adapted to fit my assumptions.

Reference the following article which describes an overall traffic queuing application:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-simpy.html?dwzone=linux

Please advise if there's a more realistic alternative approach or pre-existing
modules to tweak.

Thank you in advance for your kind consideration and support.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in simulating of website traffic, but maybe you can use some Monte Carlo simulation to create a statistical representation of real traffic they have on the test site.
Excuse the lack of particulars, and the first idea of what appeared to me, not tested. I'm not sure that I understood your problem.

Post Scriptum.

I think about your and I what to sure. You want to test the efficiency of the website, and you have some historical data of traffic on this website?